# Is there a way for an iOS app to periodically run code while inactive?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I want my app to be able to run some code every 5 minutes or so when it's inactive/suspended and the user is doing other stuff on the phone. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Update your question (don't reply in a comment) with details about why you need to run code every 5 minutes. That will help people offer proper solutions.

Comment: And also the answer is "no." If you describe those details, then we can probably help you find a solution that doesn't involve running every 5 minutes or so. (As rmaddy notes, though, update the question to more clearly state what you're trying to do, do not just create a running comment thread.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way you can run code in background, although I would not recommend doing so every 5 minutes:

> If your app’s server-based content changes infrequently or at
>   irregular intervals, you can use background notifications to notify
>   your app when new content becomes available. A background notification
>   is a remote notification that doesn’t display an alert, play a sound,
>   or badge your app’s icon. It wakes your app in the background and
>   gives it time to initiate downloads from your server and update its
>   content.

Essentially, you can send push notification that would look like the sample here:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

The `content-available` flag lets the push notification wake the app up in the background.
You cannot include any alert field or anything that would indicate it should be a visible notification or else this flag would essentially be ignored from my experience.

You would then handle this here: `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`

Basically got this whole answer straight from the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

> the system may throttle the delivery of background notifications if
>   the total number becomes excessive

The above quote is why I wouldn't recommend doing it every 5 minutes.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish so I do not know if this would suit your needs or if this is the optimal answer for you without more details.

Comment: Good point. (voted.) However, as you point out, There are vague limits on how often you can do this that are outside your control. Also, push notifications require server support, and sending messages to each user.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

Apple is very strict about when and where it lets apps run in the background. Normally you get told when you are being swapped to inactive, and can request background time to finish what you are doing. The time you get is 3 minutes at most, if memory serves. After that you get suspended (in memory but not receiving processor time) and can get terminated at any time without warning once you're suspended.

Apple does allow a tiny subset of apps to run in the background indefinitely, but is very strict about which apps qualify. Turn-by-turn navigation apps, music apps, and VOIP style communications apps are the only categories I remember.